# Running Total in the Dataflow

Tags: data, einstein-analytics, dataflow

I am trying to use computerelative transformation to calculate running total and running into this error:

> Transform dim/mea not found in Edgemart

My SAQL is

```
case when previous('weeklymeasure') == null then current('weeklymeasure') else (current('weeklymeasure') + previous('fieldnameofthiscomputedfield')) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

case
when previous('*fieldnameofthiscomputedfield*') is null then current('weeklymeasure')
else (current('weeklymeasure') + previous('*fieldnameofthiscomputedfield*'))
end